# Weird SFML error with window

Tags: c++, window, sfml

I am learning the basics of SFML (enough to make a basic pong game), but I keep getting this strange error with the window. When the window launches sometimes it has a black background (as intented), but about 50% of the time it seems to look like what was behind the window when it launched. I get no errors at compile time.

Here is the bit of the code that I think is causing problems:

```
//Game loop
while(window.isOpen()){
    sf::Event Event;


    while(window.pollEvent(Event)){

        //Getting input
        switch(Event.type){
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            window.close();
        break;

        case sf::Event::KeyPressed:

            switch(Event.key.code){

            case sf::Keyboard::Right:
                std::cout << "Right Key Pressed" << std::endl;
            break;

            case sf::Keyboard::Left:
                std::cout << "Left Key Pressed" << std::endl;
            break;

            case sf::Keyboard::Up:
                std::cout << "Up key pressed" << std::endl;
            break;
            }

        break;
        }

    }
   window.display();
}
return 0;
}
```

This is how I am making my window:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(screenWidth, screenHeight), "Pong!", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
```

Is there something extreemly obvious I am missing?

Also I am using Linux with xfce4 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not really understand your problem, but did you try to clear the window ?

add "window.clear();" just before "window.display();"